# Conditionally hide fields during data entry but show all filled in fields when viewing form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not quite new with Access but am new to VBA.

I have a main form (MainFrm) and a sub form (SubFrm). On the sub form, if a person answers "Yes" to GeneralQuestion, then they have to answer Question1 and Question2 is immediately hidden. If a person answers "No" to GeneralQuestion, then they have to answer Question2 and Question1 is immediately hidden. I set Question1 and Question2 default Visible=No on the property sheet.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub GeneralQuestion_Change()
If Me.GeneralQuestion.Value = "Yes" Then
Me.Question1.Visible = True
Me.Question2.Visible = False
End If

If Me.GeneralQuestion.Value = "No" Then
Me.Question1.Visible = False
Me.Question2.Visible = True
End If

End Sub
```

My problem is during the data entry process of the form, the appropriate fields are shown/hidden if they answer Yes/No to GeneralQuestion but when you go to view the MainFrm for old forms, I don't see either of the SubFrm fields (I assume this is because I set the default Visible=No and it's set to visible based on a Change() event).

Is there any way to add another line of code to make the fields visible when viewing the MainFrm? Or is there a better event than Change() to make the fields visible conditionally?

Thanks!

Comment: youre right in saying the problem is in the data entry process - the visible=yes only fires during tat event which you have it set to. maybe, set visible to yes always and set enabled to be true base don your previous criteria

Answer (score 0):

In the On Current event for the main form, do this:

```
Dim ctl As Control

Set ctl = Me.Questions.Form.Question1
ctl.Visible = True

Set ctl = Me.Questions.Form.Question2
ctl.Visible = True
```

Here, `Questions` is the name of the control on the main form that encapsulates the sub-form. The name of this control will generally be different from the name of the sub-form itself; the sub-form is merely the control source for the control in the main form.

If you click in the sub-form from the main form, your sub-form logic will still fire just fine. When you click back out into the main form and bring up a new main record, the main form logic shown here will fire and both fields in the sub-form will be visible.